# Access GLSL Uniforms after shaders have used them

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've noticed that my shaders are performing a calculation that I need in the CPU code. Is it possible for me to load that results of that calculation into a uniform array, and then access that uniform from the CPU once the GPU has finished working?

Comment: You can't modify uniforms from shaders. What you can do is to save computation results into a texture, or use so-called transform feedback buffers, or use compute shaders.

Comment: From what I can tell, transform feedback buffers won't be useful to me, since its a per-pixel calculation performed in the fragment shader currently.

With regards to the texture, how do you go about accessing that outside of the shader if I can't modify uniforms? Can an "out" variable output to anywhere other than the next shader?

Comment: Make your shader output computation results as colors. Render what you need into a framebuffer and then use `glReadPixels` to copy your data into RAM.

Comment: From what you're saying, it means that I can't do two things with the same shader. I want to be able to render my scene, but also return part of the calculation back to my program, using just 1 shader. If I understand right, I need to instead render my calculations to a framebuffer and use that on the CPU, and render the scene separately. However, the data is a 3D array, and to my knowledge, framebuffers are 2D. Can you have a 3D framebuffer?

Comment: Use [image load/store](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store)

Comment: Framebuffers have multiple attachement points (for textures/renderbuffers), so you can render your scene into one of them, and put your data into a different one(s). If that's not enough, you can use the trick that pleuron suggested, or possibly look into compute shaders.

Comment: I don't think image load/store is suitable because it limits you to 8 images, and i'm working with  a little bit more data than that. with regards to the renderbuffer, I'm assuming you use 2D textures. How many textures can one renderbuffer use? ie, I'm not sure how many data points there are, but if the 2d texture is storing x * y data points, can I have up to x textures? As for compute shaders, I was hoping I could look into using CUDA later, but it seems more and more like I will have to start with it.

Comment: In addition to image load/store, you can use SSBOs. You say "I'm assuming you use 2D textures" but there is no reason why you have to use 2D textures specifically, you can use any kind of texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write arbitrary amounts of data through either [Image Load/Store](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store) or [SSBOs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object). While the number of image variables is restricted in image load/store, those variables can refer to [buffer textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture) or [array textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture). Either of which give you access to a more-or-less arbitrarily large amount of data to write to:

```
layout(rgba32f, writeOnly) imageBuffer buffer;

imageStore(buffer, valueOffset1, value1);
imageStore(buffer, valueOffset2, value2);
imageStore(buffer, valueOffset3, value3);
imageStore(buffer, valueOffset4, value4);
```

SSBOs make this even easier:

```
layout(std430) buffer Data
{
    float giantArray[];
};

giantArray[valueOffset1] = data1;
giantArray[valueOffset2] = data2;
giantArray[valueOffset3] = data3;
giantArray[valueOffset4] = data4;
```

However, note that [any such writes will be *unordered*](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Incoherent_Memory_Access) with regard to writes from other shader invocations. So overwriting such data will be... problematic. And you'll need an appropriate `glMemoryBarrier` call before you try to read from it.

But if all you're doing is a compute operation, you ought to be using dedicated [compute shaders](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there is no way of retreiving uniform data from your GPU. But you could execute the calculation and set the output color to something you can identify on your screen depending on the expected result of your calculation. For exmaple:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main() {
    if( Something you're trying to debug )
        color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
    else
        color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

That's the only way I know of, and I use it all the time.